# Destroy the app and stop the service in two activities

Tags: android, service

After Launching the app, the  `MainActivity` is created  which starts background tracking  service. On the other hand, the user can use a  checkbox list in the main activity to select his interested routes where the items of the checkbox list represents the routes.

After clicking the submit button, the alarmManager starts firing the data to the `IntentService` class every 30 seconds. Subsequently, connection with the server is established and retrieving data to the `MapActivity` is started after the user was redirected to the `MapActivity`.

The user is able to stop and start the background service by using an icon in the menu of the both activities. I am facing problem to destroy the app  in the case describes below.

With the current code:

- After launching the app I can stop the service in the mainActivity and destory the app.
- after launching the app when I change from the main activity to the map activity , I can stop and start the service as well as destroy the app with opening Mapactivity.
- When I go as the following (mainActivity->mapActivity->MainAtivity->MapActivity) and closed the app with opening map view the app is not being destroyed and the service is not stoped. Also the `onDestroy()` in MapActivity is not being invoked. Here the app opens with the map view again.

But when I do the following:
adding startService(i)(as the code snippet the four lines below) to the `onStart()` in the MapActivity after `bindService`  I can destroy the app as well  stoping and starting the service but the problem here is I dont want to start the service every time I am going from the MainActivity to the MapActivity since if the user stops the service in the MainActivity it must stay off when he goes from the main to the map.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to TrackingService.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection,    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);            
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
    startService(i);
}
```

How can I destroy the app in this case in the MapActivity?
**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        AsyncTaskCallback {
boolean serviceStatus = true;
TrackingService mService;
boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.route_available);
        // Start the TrackingService class.
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        startService(i);        

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        System.out.println("ABC MainActivity onOptionsItemSelected was invoked.");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_toggle:

            if (serviceStatus) {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.off);
                item.setTitle("OFF");
                serviceStatus = false;
                mService.stopTrackingService();
            } else {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.on);
                item.setTitle("ON");
                serviceStatus = true;
                Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
                startService(i);
                System.out.println("ABC MainActivity onOptionsitemSelected   ON");
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();        
        // Bind to TrackingService.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);            
        //To start the onPrepareOptionsMenue() after returning from the map activity to change the icon of the toggle button.
        invalidateOptionsMenu();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //13.08.15
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            System.out.println("ABC MainActivity onStop() - unbindService(mConnection) was invoked. " + mBound);
            mBound = false;
        }else{
            System.out.println("ABC MainActivity onStop() - unbindService(mConnection) was invoked. " + mBound);
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class); 
        stopService(i);

        mService.stopTrackingService();
    }
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;          
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBound = false;         
        }
    };

}
```

**MapActivity**

```
   public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
            ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
         boolean serviceStatus;
        TrackingService mService;
        boolean mBound = false;

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            // Bind to TrackingService.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

//          Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
//          startService(i);
        }

        /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
        private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance

                LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
                mService = binder.getService();
                mBound = true;
                //System.out.println("ABC Map onServiceConnected() - " + mBound);

            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

                mBound = false;
                //System.out.println("ABC Map onServiceDisconnected() - mBound");

            }
        };
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();         
            if (mBound) {
                unbindService(mConnection);
                mBound = false;
            }       

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            markerMap.clear();
            stopAlarm();

            Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class); 
            stopService(i);
            mService.stopTrackingService();

        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_toggle:

                if (serviceStatus) {
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.off);
                    item.setTitle("OFF");
                    serviceStatus = false;
                    mService.stopTrackingService();
                    System.out.println("ABC Map onOptionsitemSelected OFF");
                } else {
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.on);
                    item.setTitle("ON");
                    serviceStatus = true;
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
                    startService(i);
                }

            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
    }
```

**TrackingService class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback,
        LocationListener {
LocationManager lm;
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {  
        return mBinder;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        detectLocation();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void detectLocation() {
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 12 * 1000, 0,
                this);

    }
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        TrackingService getService() {
            return TrackingService.this;
            }
       }

        public void stopTrackingService(){
        if(lm != null){
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
           }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: quick solution I can think of is in the Service you track number of binded elements(activities in this case) and when the number reaches 0 the service stops itself? or start the service from the application class and close it when the application called to be closed

Comment: @DanielMendel: And how can I count the binded elements?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so from a quick look into the documentation of the [Service Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle):

> A bound service:
>
> The service is created when another component (a
>   client) calls bindService(). The client then communicates with the
>   service through an IBinder interface. The client can close the
>   connection by calling unbindService(). Multiple clients can bind to
>   the same service and when all of them unbind, the system destroys the
>   service. (The service does not need to stop itself.)

So you don't suppose to have any problem at all, the service will die when no one is bound to him.